# Ring shape in android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, android-shape

I have the following `xml` in drawable folder (`circle_status.xml`) to create a ring:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="15dp"
    android:thickness="10dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="#ababf2" />
</shape>
```

And I insert the drawable as a background for a RelativeLayout, as next:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_Status"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_status" />
```

The problem is that a circle appears in the RelativeLayout, not a ring.

Comment: Please upload screen shot of your result and your desired result

Comment: I can't post images, sorry :(  But, it's simple, I have a circle and I'd like a ring.

Comment: Add an image in any portal and share the link,. Only if i understand i may be of any help to u.

Comment: Your code make a ring in real devive (android 3.2) but a disk in Graphical Layout Editor in Eclipse. perhaps a bug with it?

Comment: No, I'm testing it in a real device and draw a circle not a ring. Thanks

Comment: I also tested and I have a ring ... on what android version do you test?

Comment: SteveR you are rigth, I'm testing again today, and it work perfectly in a real device. Thanks

Comment: I know I'm late, but I guess your emulator was too small and the thickness on shape was filling the ring...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I answer myself.

It seems the problem is in the Graphical Layout Editor of Eclipse, the code works fine in a real device.

Comment: I couldn't find an existing issue for this with Google, so I raised it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=92345  If you star that issue it is a tiny bit more likely to get fixed. :-)

Answer (score 34):

Note that a ring is an oval without a fill. Just with a stroke. And the view holding it, should be a perfect square.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/blue" />
</shape>
```

And the view holding it

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="10dp"
     android:layout_height="10dp"
     android:src="@drawable/ring" />
```

Comment: "A ring is an oval without a fill, just with a stroke" is just what I needed to know (and what wasn't clearly stated in developer docs).

Comment: That's not true. There's a notion of an inner radius.

Comment: "Note that a ring is an oval without a fill !!" good sentence. never thought of it :D. it works better than ring shape :D

Comment: Just a note, if you want to tint it, set a transparent solid color to prevent a full oval from appearing: `<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />`

Answer (score 12):

This hack shows a ring on both device and Android Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring" android:innerRadius="23dp" android:thickness="0dp">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ababf2" />
</shape>
```

Comment: use also android:useLevel="false" or in API Level < 20 you'll get a mess

Answer (score 5):

You must use `<stroke>` tag instead of `<solid>` tag for ring in a `<shape>` tag.
Using `<solid>` tag in a `<shape>` tag results a circle not a ring.

`<solid>` tag can be used for ring background color and `<stroke>` for ring body color.